# Issue modifying effective_cache_size in postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to enable and set a value for the effective_cache_size, and issuing a SIGHUP, but the value does not change. Running postgres 9.5.5. Based on the documentation it does not require a restart, merely a reload. 
Here is the value I inserted into postgresql.conf

```
effective_cache_size = 12GB
```

I am not calling other configuration files from within the postgresql.conf.
When I query pg_settings the source file shows /data1/pgdata/mydb/postgresql.auto.conf rather than /data1/pgdata/mydb/postgresql.conf

This gets a little more bizzare, I used

```
ALTER system set effective_cache_size = 12 GB
```

and ran

```
select pg_reload_conf;
```

when I run

```
show effective_cache_size;
```

it says 12 GB

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are editing the wrong file?

Comment: No am not, verified that. Also changed a few other config settings, and they take effect but not this.

Comment: Also: check the PG logfile. There should be a line in there, even if nothing was changed.

Comment: When I query pg_settings the source file shows /data1/pgdata/mydb/postgresql.auto.conf rather than /data1/pgdata/mydb/postgresql.conf ? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`pg_settings` shows it in blocks, typically 8KB - perhaps that's the problem.

I got the same problem - which actually led me here. I set 6GB and `pg_settings` showed 786432 and the source was `configuration file` - confusing. When I changed it to 4GB and restarted, it said 524288 - aha, so it is changing!

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-EFFECTIVE-CACHE-SIZE) for the variable says: "If this value is specified without units, it is taken as blocks, that is BLCKSZ bytes, typically 8kB."